# Showing specific inputs based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I am running into an issue that I am sure is a simple fix, I just cannot figure it out. I have multiple inputs that only show if filled out. Well after you proceed to the second section, the second select input group named, "answered-question" I wanting to check the value, so that if the value is "Yes", the next labeled input appears, else it skips the next label and goes to the label id "no-color". Since attempting to do this, none of the following inputs will display at all.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

This is what I added:

```
if($('#answered-question').val('Yes')){
            $nextLabel.has(":input").addClass("show");
        } else {
            $(":input").removeClass("show");
            $("#all-color-question").addClass("show");
        }
```

Snippet

```js
  $(".labelsGroup").each(function() {

    var $thatGroup = $(this);
    var $nextGroup = $thatGroup.next(".labelsGroup");
    var $inputs    = $thatGroup.find("input");
    var $proceed   = $thatGroup.find("button");

    $inputs.on("input", function(){
      var $nextLabel = $(this).closest("label").next("label");
      if($.trim(this.value).length > 3) {
        $nextLabel.has(":input").addClass("show");
      }
    });
 
 $('#has-color').on("change", function(){
  var $nextLabel = $(this).closest("label").next("label");
        if($('#has-color').val()){
            $nextLabel.has(":input").addClass("show");
        } else {
            $nextLabel.has(":input").removeClass("show");
        }
    });
 $('#answered-question').on("change", function(){
  var $nextLabel = $(this).closest("label").next("label");
        if($('#answered-question').val('Yes')){
            $nextLabel.has(":input").addClass("show");
        } else {
            $(":input").removeClass("show");
   $("#all-color-question").addClass("show");
        }
    });
    $proceed.on("click", function(e){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
  e.preventDefault();
      
      var allValid = $inputs.filter(function() { 
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 3;
      }).length === $inputs.length;
      // TODO: use a better validation plugin than the above

      if(allValid) { // Finally proceed!!
        $thatGroup.addClass("hide");
        $nextGroup.addClass("show");
        // TODO: Submit form using AJAX to a service
      } else {       // or Log error!!
        return alert("Please fill-in the missing fields!");
      }

    });

  });
```

```css
.labelsGroup {
 text-align: center;
}
.labelsGroup label {
 display: block;
 margin: 50px 0;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}
.labelsGroup label input, .labelsGroup label select {
 background: #fff;
 padding: 15px 15px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 width: 40%;
 font-size: 1.3em !important;
}
.labelsGroup input, .labelsGroup select {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.proceed-button {
 background: #0085A1;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border: none;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 webkit-transition: .7s ease;
 transition: .7s ease;
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
}
.proceed-button:hover {
 background: #005b6e;
 webkit-transition: .7s ease;
 transition: .7s ease;
} 
/* hide all but first label in parent */
/* hide all subsequent labelsParents */
.labelsGroup label + label,
.labelsGroup + .labelsGroup,
.hide {
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.show {
 opacity: 1 !important;
 visibility: visible !important;
 position: relative !important;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in;
 transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="labelsGroup">
   <div class="container-intro">First, let's find out a little bit about you.</div>
   <label>
   What is your name?<br>
    <input name="name" type="text"><!-- PS: use name="" instead of id=""-->
   </label>
   <label>
   Phone Number<br>
    <input name="phone-number" type="email">
   </label>
   <label>
    <button class="proceed-button">PROCEED</button>
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="labelsGroup">
   <div class="container-intro">Now let's go over existing information.</div>
   <label>
    Have a favorite color?<br>
    <select name="color-question" id="has-color">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
   </label>
   <label>
    Do you frequenly choose this color?<br>
    <select name="answered-question">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
   </label>
   <label>
    List your favorite color(s)<br>
    <input name="color-select" type="text">
   </label>
   <label id="no-color">
    Do you like all colors?<br>
    <select name="all-color-question" id="all-color-question">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
   </label>
   <label>
    <button class="proceed-button">PROCEED</button>
   </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: First thing you should do is to test if your condition is working, by showing an alert if your condition is true.

If you are using Jquery, had you try the toggle function?
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

$( ".target" ).toggle();

Comment: I am wanting the inputs to consistently use my class show/hide... just I can not get this particular one to show based on the value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two issues - one with the HTML and one with the JavaScript.

You need an id on the answered-question select. Currently it only has a name. The # selector in jQuery will only select on an ID.

```
<select name="answered-question">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

You should add an ID like the below:

```
<select name="answered-question" id="answered-question">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

The other issue is in the answered-question change script. Instead of checking if the value is Yes, you are actually setting it to Yes. You need to change the if statement from

```
if($('#answered-question').val('Yes'))
```

to

```
if($('#answered-question').val() == 'Yes')
```

I have a working JSFiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4nwpLk7a/

Comment: Thanks. This has helped, but the else in the condition is not working.